# Angular get window size onload

Tags: angular

I can do this to get the window size on resizing

`@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
resizeHandler(event: any) {
    this.isSmallScreen = event.target.innerWidth > 600;
}`

How can I get the window size on load

If the page loads when the screen size is > 600 I need `isSmallScreen` to true,

I still need the window on resize but I need the size when the page loads as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.isSmallScreen = (window.innerWidth) > 600;
}
```